# Error en guardar dato C# winForm y sql

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio

Tengo un programa que tiene que guardar un dato en un campo que es una fk en sql, es un dato que obviamente saco de otra tabla que ya tiene datos registrados. El dato lo toma la variable, hasta este punto, como pueden ver el valor lo tiene asignado, pero cuando tiene que guardarlo en la bdd me dice que la columna no permite nulos. **¿Alguien sabe por qué me da ese error, si hasta acá la variable que transfiere el dato a sql tiene un valor ya asignado?**

Adjunto método para registrarlo en la bdd:

```
public int SaveMovement(Movimientos movimientos)
    {
        SaldosEstablecidos saldosEstablecidos = new SaldosEstablecidos();
        int resultado = -1;
        string orden = @"Insert into Movimientos (Importe, 
                                                 TipoMovimiento,   
                                                 FechaRealizada, 
                                                 NumCuotaPaga, 
                                                 CantCuotas, 
                                                 Observaciones,
                                                 PagoFinalizado
                                                 ) 
                                                 values (@Importe, 
                                                         @TipoMovimiento, 
                                                         @FechaRealizada,
                                                         @NumCuotaPaga, 
                                                         @CantCuotas,
                                                         @Observaciones,
                                                         @PagoFinalizado
                                                         )"
        ;

        SqlParameter importe = new SqlParameter("@Importe", movimientos.Importe);
        SqlParameter tipoMovimiento = new SqlParameter("@TipoMovimiento", movimientos.TipoMovimiento);
        SqlParameter fechaRealizada = new SqlParameter("@FechaRealizada", movimientos.FechaRealizada);
        SqlParameter numCuotaPaga = new SqlParameter("@NumCuotaPaga", movimientos.NumCuotaPaga);
        SqlParameter cantCuotas = new SqlParameter("@CantCuotas", movimientos.CantCuotas);
        SqlParameter observaciones = new SqlParameter("@Observaciones", movimientos.Observaciones);
        SqlParameter pagoFinalizado = new SqlParameter("@PagoFinalizado", movimientos.PagoFinalizado);
        SqlParameter seId = new SqlParameter("@SeId", movimientos.SeId);

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(orden, conexion);
        cmd.Parameters.Add(importe);
        cmd.Parameters.Add(tipoMovimiento);
        cmd.Parameters.Add(fechaRealizada);
        cmd.Parameters.Add(numCuotaPaga);
        cmd.Parameters.Add(cantCuotas);
        cmd.Parameters.Add(observaciones);
        cmd.Parameters.Add(pagoFinalizado);
        cmd.Parameters.Add(seId);  (**Hasta acá hago el seguimiento y tiene el valor. Ver captura**)

        try
        {
            Abrirconexion();
            resultado = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw new Exception("Error al tratar de guardar Movimientos", e);
        }
        finally
        {
            Cerrarconexion();
            cmd.Dispose();
        }
        return resultado;
    }
```

Respecto a la base de datos, así tengo la query:

```
Create table Movimientos(
Id_Mov int primary key identity not null, <br>
Importe decimal(18, 02) not null, <br>
TipoMovimiento varchar(20) not null, <br>
FechaRealizada DateTime not null, <br>
NumCuotaPaga int not null, <br>
CantCuotas int not null, <br>
Observaciones nvarchar (200) null, <br>
CodMovimiento int null, <br>
PagoFinalizado varchar(2) not null, <br>
SeId int not null <br>
) <br>

alter table Movimientos
add CONSTRAINT FK_Movimientos_ToSaldosEstablecidos FOREIGN KEY (SeId) REFERENCES  <br>SaldosEstablecidos(Id_SE) <br>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Perooooo... en tu select no esta ese campo.. te falto agregarlo en la lista del insert ;)

Comment: Ah caray qué pendejo, gracias! Si querés ponerlo como respuesta para que te la marque a vos, sería un golaso.

Comment: ya tenes una respuesta.. pero igual me suena mas a un error tipografico que a otra cosa.. no hay un problema real.. solo te olvidaste un campo...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Por lo que veo en el query "orden" te falta agregar SeId, te quedaría algo asi:

```
 string orden = @"Insert into Movimientos (Importe, 
                                                 TipoMovimiento,   
                                                 FechaRealizada, 
                                                 NumCuotaPaga, 
                                                 CantCuotas, 
                                                 Observaciones,
                                                 PagoFinalizado,
                                                 SeId
                                                 ) 
                                                 values (@Importe, 
                                                         @TipoMovimiento, 
                                                         @FechaRealizada,
                                                         @NumCuotaPaga, 
                                                         @CantCuotas,
                                                         @Observaciones,
                                                         @PagoFinalizado,
                                                         @SeId)";
```

Ya que estas haciendo todo manual, tienes que verificar bien la consulta.